# Find and subsitute a portion of a const char array

Tags: c++, string, arrays

My problem is the following:

- a `const char*` is provided to the function in which I would like to perform the operation I am going to describe
- what is provided is a filename (full absolute path included) of indeterminate length
- I would like to locate the occurrence of the substring `output` and replace it with `input`
- the output of these operations must be another `const char*` (too much code to change to replace it with a `std::string`)

What I was thinking to do is the following

```
string name(filename); //filename is the "const char*" provided by the caller of the function
string portion("output");
name.replace(name.find(insert),insert.length(),"input");
const char* newfilename = (char*)name.c_str();
```

Now, my questions:

- would do this work?
- is there a better way to obtain what I need?

Thanks to anyone that will help.

Federico

Comment: Why the cast in the last line??

Comment: @Paul R: Because it will result in Undefined Behaviour (if the `char const*` is obtained from a local `std::string` and returned from the function).

Comment: @Paul: because I would like to find out if there are better options before implementing it

Comment: How is the function supposed to return a char-pointer without requiring the consumer to clean up the memory? Sounds like you'll have to *add* a lot of new code just to add some basic memory correctness (not to speak of exception safety). So why not bite the bullet and use `std::string` everywhere.

Comment: @Kerrek: I know. This program is hell from that point of view (apparently the original programmer was not a real fan of standard c++ classes/libraries/functions), I am trying to do things bit by bit (almost in the literal sense of it)

Comment: "too much code to change to replace it with a std::string". PLEASE TRY ):! If you are not using RAII then your code probably contains bugs. Even if it is a lot of work, it **will** pay off to change your code to use `std::string` (or at least `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`) so that ownership semantics are clearly laid out in the code and destruction is managed by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, but you don't need the cast on `name.c_str()` (in fact, it's wrong: `c_str()` [returns a `const char *`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)).

But the pointer you get from `name.c_str()` is invalidated as soon as you modify `name`, or when `name` goes out of scope.  So don't try returning `newfilename` from a function, for instance.

If you need it to persist, you have no option but to dynamically allocate memory.  Standard practice would be to use a smart pointer to automatically manage deallocation.const char *, you have no option but to manage this yourself.  So you could do:

```
char *newfilename = new char[name.length() + 1];
strcpy(newfilename, name.c_str());
return newfilename;
...

delete [] newfilename;
```

---

<sub>* Well, standard practice would be to use a `std::string`!  It only gets tricky if you need to interface with a legacy C API.</sub>

Comment: I understand the problem with the pointer, and I am sorry for not having said this earlier.
I will then `sprintf()` the new filename to a member of a class (appending the new extension)

Comment: @GiladNaor: unfortunaterly, no.